# Excel VBA Runtime error '1004' can't identify a solution

Tags: excel, vba

I've been having trouble with the below module and no matter where I look, i.e. stackoverflow or elsewhere, I am unable to find a solution. Here is the code below:

```
Sub Test()
Dim IE As Object
Dim HTML As HTMLDocument
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("D6:D1000") = "" ' erase previous data
Range("D6:D1000").Select

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "https://www.example.com"
    'Set HTML = IE.document
    Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

        compName = .document.getElementsByClassName("title")
        compName = Replace(compName, Chr(10), Chr(13))
        compName = Split(compName, Chr(13))
        Range("D6").Resize(UBound(compName)) = Application.Transpose(compName)

        .Quit
    End With

End Sub
```

I am getting a runtime error ('1004' Application-defined or object-defined error) on the following line

```
Range("D6").Resize(UBound(compName)) = Application.Transpose(compName)
```

I had this line working yesterday, however, I've been making a few changes today and now this line won't run. Can anybody identify a solution?

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns a collection. Did you mean `compName = .document.getElementsByClassName("title")(0)` (gets the first item in collection)

Comment: I want it to start at the first item and then loop and add each item that has the class name "title" within the webpage. Unfortunately, the above returns the same error.

Comment: @O.Williams Maybe `compName` has to be declared as a variable first?

Comment: The macro has worked in the past without declaring this variable. I can't see why this would be an issue now. I'm open to this suggestion, however, the line in question is expecting an Array as a result of pulling a collection but I can't see a way of declaring this as an array

Comment: When you transpose `compName`, the rank of its dimensions is swapped. That means you can't use it to determine the size of the target `Range` until ***after*** it is transposed.